# Basic Hello, Rails! not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I am very new to ruby and rails and I'm following this tutorial exactly: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I am having trouble with the basic "Hello, Rails!" output on the localhost:3000 as even when I follow along and make the appropriate changes to

```
app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
```

and

```
config/routes.rb
```

localhost:3000 still displays the default Ruby on Rails Welcome screen instead of "Hello, Rails!"

in the file

```
app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
```

I have the following code:

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
```

in the file

```
config/routes.rb
```

I have the following code:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
   root :to => 'welcome#index'


end
```

and I initially generated the controller with

```
rails generate controller welcome index
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

I removed the public/index folder and now get the following error in the browser:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Welcome#index

Showing C:/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:


  (in C:/blog/app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <head>
4:   <title>Blog</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>

Rails.root: C:/blog
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__607271608_36500496'
```

EDIT 2:

rake routes gives:

```
welcome_index GET /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
        root           /                   welcome#
```

EDIT 3:

source of welcome.js.coffee:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
```

source of Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: You need to remove public/index.html

Comment: I did this and get an new error, please see edit

Comment: Looks like something wrong with asset compilation. Show the source of assets/javascripts/welcome.js.coffee and the Gemfile please.

Comment: @Max Woolf. Please see edit 3

Answer (score 1):

Check if your controller file is welcome_controller.rb. Also Check if the class name is "WelcomeController".

EDIT:

It seems that you are getting a ExecJS exception. Please add a javascript runtime to the gemfile:

```
gem  'therubyracer'
```

I hate windows.

Comment: Hi, I have done that too by uncommenting the line gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby in the Gemfile. Same result

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning to use turbolinks you can avoid installation of turbolinks with rails by running `new your_project_name --skip-turbolinks` when creating your rails project. This way you will avoid this kind of bugs while you are learning the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

go to

```
C:/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb line #6
```

and remove the javascript line.

But this is really stupid and I think the real solution is to switch to linux.

Answer (score 0):

yes,truly worked for me. deleted following line from `C:/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```